# Chrome keeps caching my old page until I hit the refresh button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, browser-cache

I'm having a really strange behavior with my `SPA` in Chrome. I'm running a local IIS Server with an `AngularJS` frontend. I'm using `Gulp` to bust-cache all my Javascript and CSS files. Recently I discovered that my site was loading old HTML files and this is due to angular `$templateCache`, so I used `gulp-angular-templatecache` to solve this but then a new problem appeared.

When I turn on my PC, start the IIS server and load my application with Chrome by typing `localhost` in the URL bar, Chrome loads everything from cache, so I get old JS, CSS and HTML files (I see that chrome is loading an old `index.html` file) but If I go to some other route like `localhost/mainPage` it loads all my new files and everything works as intended. After that, if I go to `localhost` again, the old site is loaded from cache again!!

I'm not an expert but it seems a very weird behavior. Is this a Chrome bug? Is it Chrome's fault or something in my `AngularJS` `SPA`?

In my `Web.config` I have this to disable caching of `index.html`:

```
  <!-- Disable index.html cache -->
  <location path="index.html">
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

And this to maximize caching time for all the other files:

```
<system.webServer>    
   <staticContent>
      <!-- Cache busting for 1 year (max recommended value) -->
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
   </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score -1):

There's these two scenarios:

- When developing, you should use the `disable cache` option that Google Chrome provides. For this, open Devtools (Chrome menu > more tools.. > Devtools), go to the network tab and check the box that says **Disable cache**
- When releasing to production, you should use any file revisioning tool on minified files. This appends a hash to the file's name (like scripts.472bc7.js) to avoid cache issues with end user's browsers

Comment: I'm already appending a hash to each file (cache-bust) and that's the problem, chrome keeps getting and old html file